# Where is the default location of ssl certs?

Tags: ssl

I have a quick question maybe someone could help me with.

I downloaded a few apps and ISO's from source forge today and they seemed to have disappeared. They weren't in the default down load folder or in the Firefox download cache.

So anyway, I started clicking around in my files trying to locate them and I came across a file string that I hadn't seen before. /var/spool/postfix/etc/ssl/certs. And in it, I found all these ssl CA and Root CA certificates (maybe 200 to 300 of them). I can open them and see pub. key.

Algorithm, Signature (huge table of numbers) and a bunch of other info that seems sensitive. I know very little about encryption and secure sockets, so I was wondering if this is a normal place to find such items.

By the way I don’t use local mail service on the machine. So I don't Know why anything would be in there. Thank You. B

Answer (score 0):

/var/spool/... is definitly not a place to expect certificates. In linux they are usually below /etc/ssl/certs

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. So were would you suggest I go from here. I'm 99.9 percent sure it's a security issue. I have  machines total, 2 Compaq laptops and 2 Lenovo desktops. This type of thing is common at my house. Config files get misconfigured by themselves. It allways seems to be the most vulnerable ones. Samba, Mail, Cups, Avahi, SSH. Its been going on for about 10 years.

Comment: A remote analysis is not really useful in this case.